# Finding the shortest word ladder between two given words and a dictionary

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to find shortest ladder from a dictionary between two given words. All the words including the given one and in the dictionary have same number of characters. In one pass, only one character may be changed and shortest path is required. Ex.: given: "hit" and "cil" Dic: ["hil", "hol", "hot", "lot", "lit", "lil"] So, the answer should be "hit"->"hil"->"cil"

I have tried to solve this problem using BFS; by finding next word in the dictionary and checking if that is adjacent to the popped item from the queue. This approach won't give me the shortest path though:

If, I try to replace each letter with 26 alphabets and if the resulting word is present in the dictionary, accept that: still this approach won't give me shortest path. Ex.: Here, it shall give me: hit->lit->lot->hot->hol->lil->cil

Probably, the better approach would be to construct a tree first and then find the shortest path in the tree from starting word to ending word.

I know, there are solutions to this problem on this forum but none of them explains the algorithm. I am new to BFS and so not much familiar.
I am interested in knowing how to find one of the shortest path and if several then all shortest paths.

Comment: sounds a lot like a travelling salesman problem, I cant imagine there is a solution other than brute force, answer your own question if you find a nice algorithm

Comment: Did you read about Levenshtein distance?

Comment: How big is the dictionary? How many words would there be in the dictionary?

Comment: "Probably, the better approach would be to construct a tree first and then find the shortest path in the tree from starting word to ending word."... Something like a trie is a better data structure for a dictionary, but not for this problem since the trie is very dependent on letter sequence.  Words that differ in the 0th char will be more distant than those that differ in the nth char.

Comment: BFS sounds like a good solution. Are you sure that you did not make a mistake when implementing it?

Comment: Dictionary, let's say is small. Consider the example dictionary that I gave. The problem is I can still find the length of shortest path by emptying the queue completely, and checking the minimum length but how to construct the path from it. (shortest path). I have adopted kind of brute-force, checking all possibilities.

Comment: Thinking aloud, from the starting point, you'd create children that represent all "differ-by-one" words that are in the dictionary ("hit", "hot", "lit" and "lil"). Then, for each of these nodes (breadth-first) you'd create children for all differ-by-one words. Repeat until you hit the end word. Because you're processing breadth-first, you probably don't need to worry about pruning children that go "back towards" the starting point, since you'll hit the shortest route before it matters too much (though if you don't _know_ there's a solution, this might lead to an endless loop).

Comment: BFS or A-Star (with Levenshtein distance as heuristic) should works. You do have a bug in your implementation (don't stop once found, doesn't mark node as visited correctly, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is a bit brute force, but may be a good starting point.

If the target word is equal to the start word, or has [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) 1 the result is `[start, target]` and you are done.

Otherwise you have to find all members of the dictionary with Levenshtein distance 1 from the start word. If one of them has Levenshtein distance 1 to the target word, the result is `[start, word, target]` and you're done. Otherwise, you recurse with every word in the chosen list as a start and the target as the target and prepend `start` to the shortest result.

pseudo code - a bit python like:

```
myDict = {"hil", "hol", "hot", "lot", "lit", "lil"}

used_wordlist = {}

shortestWordLadder(start, target):
    if start == target or levenshtein(start, target) = 1:
        return [start, target]

    current_wordlist = [x for x in myDict
                              if x not in used_wordlist and
                              levenshtein(ladder[-1], x) = 1]

    if current_wordlist.size = 0:
        return null

    for word in current_wordlist:
        if levenshtein(word, target) == 1:
            return [start, word, target]

     used_wordlist.insert_all(current_wordlist)
     min_ladder_size = MAX_INT
     min_ladder = null

     for word in currrent_wordlist:
         ladder = shortestWordLadder(word, target)

         if ladder is not null and ladder.size < min_ladder_size:
             min_ladder_size = ladder.size
             min_ladder = ladder.prepend(start)

     return min_ladder
```

**Possible optimization:**

I considered to reuse the matrix, that `levenshtein(start, target)` would create internally, but I could not gain enough confidence, that it would work in all cases. The idea was to start at the bottom right of the matrix and chose the smallest neighbor, that would create a word from the dictionary. Then continue with that position. If no neighbor of the current cell creates a word from the dictionary, we'd have to backtrack until we find a way to a field with value 0. If backtracking brings us back to the bottom right cell, there is no solution.

I am not sure now, that there might not be solutions, that you'd maybe ignore that way. If it finds a solution, I am pretty confident, that it is one of the shortest.

At the moment I lack the time to think it through. If that proves to not be a complete solution, you could use it as an optimization step instead of the `levenshtein(start, target)` call in the first line of `shortestWOrdLadder()`, since the algorithm gives you the Levenshtein distance and, if possible, the shortest path.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to build a graph over the words in the dictionary, where a node represents a word and there is an edge from a <-> b if b can be transformed from a by changing only one character from a (and of course, the vice versa is also true). This process will take O(n*n) time where n is the no. of words in the dictionary.
 How to do this is as follows : 
For each word build frequency array of characters, call it farr, which is 26 length long, and farr[i] tells how many times character i, in alphabetical order occurs in word, and then in a nested loop running n*n times you just need to compare the entries of frequency table for the words, they must differ by only one character in order to have an edge from word a to b.
Also Note that the edges are undirected(in both directions) in this graph.
After building the complete graph on words of dictionary, add the question word as well to graph. And then go ahead with the BFS searching for the target word from node of initial word, where the transformation required is initial word -> target word.
Now say you find target word at level 'i', while exploring from initial word then the shortest path is 'i' units long.

Comment: Directed graph should do as I need to move in only 1 direction. The process should be O(n*Constant); where n is the number of words in the dictionary and m is the size of a word.

Comment: I feel that in the worst case you may have to draw an edge between all the words, and in worst case the size of word will be long as no. of words in the dictionary,so the worst time complexity is O(n*n), ignoring the constant factors as always.

Comment: I don't know how will you draw a directed edge, but i feel that the directed graph will not solve the problem because although you will move in one direction but once the graph is built over the words of dictionary, you don't know that source word will be attached to which all nodes in the graph, and which paths you may require to follow to reach the end word. It's safer to have bidirectional edges.

Comment: I have used a tree. I don't need edges between all nodes but between words adjacent to each other and that too not all. If s and a are adjacent and s and b are adjacent then a and b would be adjacent but I don't need an edge between them. I have provided a solution to this using tree, in the answer with code

Comment: You have fixed the root, that means you are modeling the Data Structure for just one pair of source and target, and here I made mistake. I thought you want to build the data structure for only the words of dictionary, and then you will get some source and target pairs, may be many , and for each one you have to report answer as quickly as possible. But because that is not the case, then tree constructions is not an issue, because anyway after building th graph you will do a BFS, which will produce a BFS tree .

Comment: Yes, I would fix the root. However, I would also be okay if any one shortest path is revealed or all the shortest paths (if more than 1) if complexity is reduced. Right now, my solution has exponential complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a solution by adopting the following approach:
1.) I have built a tree from the dictionary first, assuming the starting point to be the given word; and finding all words adjacent to this word and so on
2.) Next I have tried to construct all possible paths from given word to the end word using this tree.

Complexity: O(n*70 + 2^n-1 * lg(n)) = O(2^n-1*lg(n)) Here n is the number of words in the dictionary, 70 comes out as the range of ASCII values from 65 to 122 (A to a), I have taken a round figure here. Complexity is exponential as expected. 
Even, after certain optimizations, worst case complexity won't change.

Here is the code I wrote (its tested by me and works. Any bugs or suggestions would be highly appreciated.):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <deque>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string str;
    vector<node *> children;
    node(string s) {
        str = s;
        children.clear();
    }
};

bool isAdjacent(string s1, string s2) {
    int table1[70], table2 [70];
    int ct = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
        table1[i] = 0;
        table2[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        table1[((int)s1[i])- 65] += 1;
        table2[((int)s2[i])- 65] += 1;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
        if (table1[i] != table2[i])
            ct++;
        if (ct > 2)
            return false;
     }
     if (ct == 2)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}

void construct_tree(node *root, vector<string> dict) {
    deque<node *> q;
    q.push_back(root);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        node *curr = q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        if (dict.size() == 0)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < dict.size(); i++) {
            if (isAdjacent(dict[i], curr->str)) {
                string n = dict[i];
                dict.erase(dict.begin()+i);
                i--;
                node *nnode = new node(n);
                q.push_back(nnode);
                curr->children.push_back(nnode);
            }
        }
    }
}

void construct_ladders(stack<node *> st, string e, vector<vector <string> > &ladders) {
    node *top = st.top();
    if (isAdjacent(top->str,e)) {
        stack<node *> t = st;
        vector<string> n;
        while (!t.empty()) {
            n.push_back(t.top()->str);
            t.pop();
        }
        ladders.push_back(n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < top->children.size(); i++) {
        st.push(top->children[i]);
        construct_ladders(st,e,ladders);
        st.pop();
    }
}

void print(string s, string e, vector<vector<string> > ladders) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ladders.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = ladders[i].size()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            cout<<ladders[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<e<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<string> dict;
    string s = "hit";
    string e = "cog";

    dict.push_back("hot");
    dict.push_back("dot");
    dict.push_back("dog");
    dict.push_back("lot");
    dict.push_back("log");

    node *root = new node(s);
    stack<node *> st;
    st.push(root);

    construct_tree(root, dict);

    vector<vector<string> > ladders;
    construct_ladders(st, e, ladders);

    print(s,e,ladders);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Point is if one could settle with only one shortest path, is there a better solution to find it? All paths would anyhow be exponential.

Comment: **Issue 1** The complexity analysis is wrong. O(n\*70 + 2^n-1 \* lg(n)) = O(lgn) , is wrong, the actual complexity is equivalent to O(n+2^n\*lg(n)) and anything of the form O(2^n \* lg(n)) is disasterous. Your code is not actually having that complexity. **Issue 2.** The exploring a path between two nodes of a tree will never go exponential, if you are really confident about your code that you have actually built a tree , then there only exists a single path between any two nodes in the tree and therefore you are not going to see more than one path, also the complexity will be polynomial.

Comment: For a better performance you are advised either not to use a vector of string, rather use a queue of string, Or do not delete the strings from vector rather have a separate **bool** vector named **exists** and put exists[i] = true, only if ith string exists in the original vector. Deletion step is costly. Using a character array is another better optimization possible rather than a string, as string comes with lots of overhead.

Comment: @prem ktiw. Makes sense to me. I corrected the value though. I think I have messed in the code for construct_ladders, which essentially go over every possible path. Complexity of this construct_ladders function comes out to be exponential for me. However, investigating each path from root to leaf and intermediate ones could be linear in n. Then, my algorithm's complexity should be O(n*70 + n*C) = O(n), which looks strange to me. How could it be so low? n*70 is for construct_tree function.